# Convert String of List to List in Python

Tags: python, django

I need to convert a string of list to List in Python. I have seen many of the similar questions but none of them works in this case.

I am passing some values through PostMan.

The key passing as a form data

```
Key =  controls
value = [CR1,CR2]
```

I am fetching the data like this

```
c_list = self._kwargs['data'].get('controls', [])
print(c-list)
print(type(c-list))
```

I am getting the following o/p

```
[CC-2,CC-3]
<class 'str'>
```

But I need to get it as a list so I have tried the following method

```
import ast
c_list = self._kwargs['data'].get('controls', [])
res = ast.literal_eval(c_list)
```

But I am getting the following Error

```
malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f82966942b0>
```

Comment: do this: `c_list = self._kwargs['data'].get('controls', []).split(',')`.

Comment: You can use split.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do the following: `strip` the brackets and `split` on the commas

```
>>> s = "[CC-2,CC-3]"
>>> s.strip('[]').split(',')
['CC-2', 'CC-3']
```